# High chart -fill pie data with xlst

Tags: xslt, highcharts, pie-chart

Client side,we are using xsl.i want to fill pie chart from xlst.i get xml file from server side like:

```
var services="<xsl:value-of  disable-output-escaping="yes" select="/doc/serviceHistory/usageList"/>";
```

how can i dynamically fill data of piechart.İ've tried below code but it doesn't work.$(document).ready(function() {

```
  var options = {
            chart: {renderTo: 'container',type: 'pie',width: 334,height: 230},
            title: {text: ''},
                                tooltip: {pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',percentageDecimals: 0},
                                plotOptions: {
                                        pie: {
                                                allowPointSelect: true,
                                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                                dataLabels: {
                                                enabled: true,
                                                color: '#000000',
                                                connectorColor: '#000000',
                                                formatter: function() {
                                                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b> ';
                                                }
                                                }
                                              }
                                },
            series: [{name: 'Allowed',
                                             data:[]
                                         }]
         };
         $.get('doc.xml', function(xml) {
            var $xml = $(xml);



            $xml.find('doc serviceHistory usageList').each(function(i, series) {
               var seriesOptions = {
                  name: $(series).find('name').text(),
                  data: []
               },
               name = [];


               $xml.find('doc serviceHistory usageList usage usageType').each(function(i, category) {
                  name[i] = $(category).text();
               });

               $(series).find('doc serviceHistory usageList usage percentage').each(function(i, point) {
                  seriesOptions.data.push([name[i],parseInt($(point).text())]);
               });
               options.series.push(seriesOptions);
            });
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you show example of your XML? Or setup jsFiddle sample? In general, your data shouldn't contain any NaN's or strings. Also, here you are setting one series:

```
        series: [{
           name: 'Allowed',
           data:[]
        }]
```

and then adding one more:

```
        options.series.push(seriesOptions);
```

So you are covering one series by another.

Comment: XML is:i want to use usageType as a title and percentage as percentage of pie slices<doc>
 <serviceHistory>
  <usageList>
   <usage>
    <usageType>Yurt </usageType>
    <percentage>10</percentage>
   </usage>
   <usage>
    <usageType>Arama  </usageType>
    <percentage>50</percentage>
   </usage>
  </usageList>
 </serviceHistory>
</doc>

Comment: So your path for that XML are wrong, see fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/203/

Answer (score 0):

This code works.I think it is more plain

```
 $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: "<xsl:value-of select="percentage"></xsl:value-of>"
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [

                     <xsl:for-each select="/a/b/c/d">
                        <xsl:variable name="totalCost">
                              <xsl:value-of select="e"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:variable>

                        <xsl:if test="$totalCost!=0">
                          ["<xsl:value-of select="usageType"></xsl:value-of>",  <xsl:value-of select="$totalCost"></xsl:value-of> ],                    
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>


                ]
            }]
        });
    });
```